# C++ Iniatializer list on vector with custom object?

Tags: c++, class, vector, std

Im trying to implement initializer_list for the vector containing my custom-class objects but im getting the error:

```
no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<std::vector<Item>>'
typedef typename iterator_traits<_OI>::value_type _ValueTypeO;
```

## Here is my custom class object

```
class Item{
    private:
        int id;
        std::string item_name;
        double item_price;
        bool item_available;
        int stock;
        ItemCategory item_category;


        Item* arrayData;
        int size;

    public:
        static int id_ref;
        Item(){}
        Item(std::string _name, double _price, ItemCategory _category);
        Item(std::string _name, double _price, int _stock, ItemCategory _category);
        Item& operator=(const Item& i);
        //Getters
        const int getId(){return id;}
        const std::string getName(){return item_name;}
        const double getPrice(){return item_price;}
        const bool getAvailable(){return item_available;}
        const int getStock(){return stock;}
        const ItemCategory getCategory(){return item_category;}
        const std::string getCategoryString();
        //Setters
        void setName(std::string n){item_name = n;}
        void setPrice(double p){item_price = p;}
        void setAvaiable(bool b){item_available = b;}
        void setStock(int s){stock = s;}
        void setCategory(ItemCategory ic){item_category = ic;}

};

//Copy operator
Item& Item::operator=(const Item& i){
    *this = i;
    return *this;
}

//Keep track of all Items created to index them.
int Item::id_ref = 0; 
const std::string Item::getCategoryString(){
    switch(item_category){
        case (ItemCategory::FOOD):
            return "Food";
        case (ItemCategory::CLOTHES):
            return "Clothes";
    }
}


Item::Item(std::string _name, double _price, ItemCategory _category):
        id{Item::id_ref++}, item_name{_name}, item_price{_price}, 
        item_available{true}, stock{1}, item_category{_category}{}

Item::Item(std::string _name, double _price, int _stock, ItemCategory _category):
    id{Item::id_ref++}, item_name{_name}, item_price{_price}, 
    item_available{true}, stock{_stock}, item_category{_category}{}
```

## This is how im trying to use the class

```
class Cart{
    private:
        std::vector<Item> customer_cart;

    public:
        Cart(){}
        Cart(std::initializer_list<Item>);
        void push(Item i){customer_cart.push_back(i);}
        void printAllItems();
        Item& operator[](int i){return customer_cart[i];}


};

Cart::Cart(std::initializer_list<Item> lst){
    copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), customer_cart);

}

void Cart::printAllItems(){
    std::cout << "Id   Name      Category     Price    Stock" << std::endl; 
    for(auto i:customer_cart){
        std::cout << i.getId() << "   " << i.getName() << "      " << i.getCategoryString()                << "         " << i.getPrice() << "      " << i.getStock() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I know that I can do this for the initializer list:

```
for(auto l: lst)
        customer_cart.push_back(l);
```

But Im only 2 days into C++ and I want to learn more stuff that will be useful in the future.

Thanks to anyone in advance for helping to fix my problem. Also any comment regarding my code (how to make it better/more efficient) is welcome. I'm coming from python so many things are kinda new for me in c++.

Comment: `std::copy` expects iterator, not container (Your may look at `std::back_inserter`). `Cart::Cart(std::initializer_list<Item> lst) : customer_cart(lst){}` would do the job.

Comment: Unrelated, think *seriously* about what is called with `*this = i;` being in your assignment operator overload (spoiler: the very same overloaded operator you're defining).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, that worked. Didnt think of that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I noticed that but it just worked. I know is bad, was just going to google some info on that. Could you give me a hand with it please?

Comment: @Jarod42 Also, I read in the c++ docs that .begin()/.end() return an iterator, not a container. What did you mean then?

Comment: I mean `std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), std::back_inserter(customer_cart))`, as `customer_cart` is a container, not an iterator.

Comment: Oh. Got confused, thanks.